# Partial Catch All Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've a rails 4.0 app hosting an ember app. The root of the app is served on `domain.com/orders`. However, using push-state, ember will handle routes within that root, like `domain.com/orders/favorite_products`.

The question is, how can I make Rails server anything after `orders` like `orders/favorites` or event longer paths `orders/favorites/name/edit/description/more/stuff/rails/shouldnt/care`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the question. I need to use an optional wildcard:

```
get 'path/to/ember-root/(*ember-stuff-ignored-by-rails)', to: 'your_controller#your_aciton'
```